# wit.ai не вернул ничего

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я отправляю на сервер аудио в формате буффера, но в ответ он ничего не вернул

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const fs = require(`fs`);
const apikey = KEY;

async function recognize(audio) {
  const body = fs.readFileSync(audio);
  const uri = `https://api.wit.ai/speech`
  const response = request.post({
    uri,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ` + apikey,
      'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg',
    },
    body
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
}
```

Вот ответ от серверта

```
{
  "entities": {},   
  "intents": [], 
  "text": "", 
  "traits": {} 
}
```

Comment: Файл то отправляется, проверяли? body не пустой?

Comment: нет, не пустой, файл отправляется